# Unable to pick content of class tag in web scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm learning web **scraping** using JSOUP and I've been trying to retrieve data of a class tag `sc-fzqBZW sc-fzoyAV eGbWXV`. I've tried replacing white spaces with dots but nothing seems to work. I'm attaching the code chunk below. I'd be very much thankful if someone pinpoints my mistake and corrects it for me.
This is the line:

> "<td . class="sc-fzqBZW sc-fzoyAV eGbWXV" kind="field"
> title="accountId">accountId required "

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading Scraper!");
        final String url = "https://apidocs.temenos.com/service/account-management#operation/getAccountClosure";

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            org.jsoup.select.Elements elements = doc.select("sc-fzqBZW.sc-fzoyAV.eGbWXV");
//original class tag = sc-fzqBZW sc-fzoyAV eGbWXV

            for (Element element : elements) {
                System.out.println("Ticker:" + element.text());

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in establising connection. /n" + "Error: " + ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation here https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

you could try smth like

```
 doc.select("td.sc-fzqBZW sc-fzoyAV eGbWXV");
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I debugged the code and turns out this is not entering in the for loop and hence the crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `sc-fzqBZW.sc-fzoyAV.eGbWXV` is missing dot at the beginning to indicate `sc-fzqBZW` is a class. Now it will match such element:

```
<sc-fzqBZW class="sc-fzoyAV eGbWXV">
```

Use `.sc-fzqBZW.sc-fzoyAV.eGbWXV`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

   //it will return "accountId" text

   elements.get(i).getElementsByTag("span").get(1).html();


   //it will return "required" text

   elements.get(i).getElementsByClass("sc-fzoWqW sc-fzplgP eDnpFZ").first().html();
 
}
```